# Derivative of sum of n terms of an AP

Tags: calculus, derivatives, arithmetic-progressions

For example in AP:  $5,13,21,29 \dots$ the sum of $n$ terms $= 4n^2+n$ and its derivative will be $8n+1$.

The coefficient of $n$ in derivative gives the common difference but what does that '$1$' signify?

And why it is not same as the equation for $n$'th term of AP ?

Comment: $$\dfrac{S_m-S_{m-1}}{m-(m-1)}=4m^2+m-\{4(m-1)^2+(m-1)\}=\cdots$$

Comment: derivative doesn't make much sense when $n\in\Bbb{N}$ it's the same like saying $(x+1)^-x^2=2x+1$ but $(x^2)'=2x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum of $n$ terms of an A.P. with first term $a$ and common difference $d$ is given by : $$S=\frac{n^2d}{2} + n(a-d/2)$$

Therefore it's derivative is :

$$S' = nd + (a-d/2)$$

Therefore coefficient of $n$ represents common difference and constant term is $a-\dfrac{d}{2}$

Note : This function isn't derivable for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, because it is discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

For a progression with general term $ak+b$, the sum for $k$ from $1$ to $n$ is

$$S(n):=n\frac{a(n+1)+2b}2,$$ and its derivative

$$S'(n)=an+\frac a2+b=an+(a+b)-\frac a2.$$

In your case, $8n-3$ yields $8n+1$ and the "$1$" is the first term minus the half common difference, $5-4$.

---

When the indexes are $0$-based, the derivative of the sum from $0$ to $n$ is

$$S'(n)=\left(n\frac{an+2b}2\right)'=an+b.$$